# Extract token from a curl request and use in another shell command

Tags: json, bash, curl

I've started picking up bash scripting and I'm stuck at something I'm trying to wrap my head around.

I have a curl command that outputs a token and I need to use it in the following command:

```
curl -k 'https://server:port/session' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"admin","password":"password"}'
```

It then outputs a token here:

```
{"token":"ac07098ad59ca6f3fccea0e2a2f6cb080df55c9a52fc9d65"}
```

I then need to use it in the follow up command

```
curl https://server:port/ -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Cookie:token=token' -d '
```

I was thinking I could output the token to a file, then have a sed command write the token to a file, then the new command use a variable where token=$token

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This is where a JSON parsing tool comes in handy (such as [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)):

```
$ echo '{"token":"ac07098ad59ca6f3fccea0e2a2f6cb080df55c9a52fc9d65"}' | jq -r .token
ac07098ad59ca6f3fccea0e2a2f6cb080df55c9a52fc9d65
```

So

```
json=$( curl -k 'https://server:port/session' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"admin","password":"password"}' )
token=$( jq -r ".token" <<<"$json" )

curl https://server:port/ -k -X POST -H "X-Cookie:token=$token" ...
```

Comment: Install WSL and have Linux on Windows.

Answer (score 10):

With no further tool than a bash (tested Centos/Rhel7/GitBash) :

```
json=$(curl -k 'https://server:port/session' \
            -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
            -d '{"username":"admin","password":"password"}') \
&& token=$(echo $json | sed "s/{.*\"token\":\"\([^\"]*\).*}/\1/g") \
&& echo "token = $token"
```

then use your authentication needing commands like that :

```
curl https://server:port/ -k -X POST \
                          -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                          -H 'X-Cookie:token=$token' -d ...'
```

Comment: Hi @teikitel

What if I am using Bearer Token in format Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ5bWFudWNoYXJpYW4iLCJleHAiOjE2MjI3OTc5Mzl9.d7yT6r8pf0QEh-sMDxNiObDSdF2K17l3WqcjHnv9800

Comment: Hello @MichaelKors, usually if the case your authentication service retruns a reponse payload containing only a string like "Bearer eyJhbG...". So it's even simpler, no need to parse it: `token=$json`. Then the http header you should use is `-H 'Authorization: $token'` instead of `-H 'X-Cookie...'`

Answer (score 1):

If Python is installed, and hopefully it is on modern systems, you can do something like:

```
OUTPUT="$(curl -k 'https://server:port/session' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"admin","password":"password"}' | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['token']")"
```

This will give you:

```
echo $OUTPUT
ec2e99a1d294fd4bc0a04da852ecbdeed3b55671c08cc09f
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `` syntax:

```
cmd1result=$(command1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | grep -Po "[a-z0-9-]+")
command2 $cmd1result
```

Comment: it works, however, I just need the "ac07098ad59ca6f3fccea0e2a2f6cb080df55c9a52fc9d65" portion without quotes. It'll always be a random 48 character string.
Example:
'X-Cookie:token=ac07098ad59ca6f3fccea0e2a2f6cb080df55c9a52fc9d65'

Comment: `$()` is the modern replacement. Backticks are literally legacy support, and have serious disadvantages -- it's easy to nest `$( $( ) )`, whereas putting backticks inside backticks is **painful**.

Comment: And your grep command strips hex digits from the token. It's thus inaccurate/corrupt, **and** (due to unnecessary use of the nonstandard option `-P`) needlessly platform-specific.

Comment: (note that the `e` in the word `token` is part of the character set that needs to be preserved, since `e` is within `[0-9a-f]` -- so just stripping a character range is quite thoroughly unworkable).